# "invalid path 0 files copied" Error while using xcopy command

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, filepath, xcopy

Hi I have this little command to copy files in a batch, which will help because I do this specific copy multiple times a day. The problem occurs while using the xcopy command. Everything is in order, but I am receiving this error: "Invalid path 0 files copied". Here is the code:

```
C:\Windows\System32\xcopy  /Y "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\mmars_pub\" "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Dropbox\MMARS\mmars_pub\"
```

I'm using the full path to the xcopy executable because I was having trouble configuring the path environment variable to function properly. I would imagine that it shouldn't affect the result though. I read somewhere about the "Prevent MS-DOS-based programs from detecting Windows" checkbox that should fix the issue, but I just can't seem to find that. Any help appreciated.

Comment: The `xcopy` command you're using isn't an MS-DOS based program. It's a Windows console program.

Comment: The `%path%` variable is set by default to use the correct folders.  If you have re-used the `path` variable then pick a different variable name.  This only pertains to the way you have to set the full path to the `xcopy` command.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**Original answer**

Remove the ending backslash from the source folder path

```
C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe  /Y "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\mmars_pub" "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Dropbox\MMARS\mmars_pub\"
```

---

**edited** 2015/10/01

While the original question used a literal path, and the indicated solution will solve the problem, there is another option. For literal paths and in cases where the path is inside a variable and could (or not) end in a backslash, it is enough to ensure that the ending backslash (if present) is separated from the quote, including an ending dot.

```
xcopy /y "x:\source\." "x:\target"
xcopy /y "%myVariable%." "x:\target"
```

This ending dot will not interfere in files/folders names. If there is and ending backslash, the additional dot will simply refer to the same folder. If there is not ending backslash as in windows files and folders can not end their names with a dot, it will be discarded.

BUT if the output of the `xcopy` command will be processed, remember that this additional dot will be included in the paths shown.

---

**note**: The solutions are above the line. Keep reading if interested on why/where there is a *problem*.

Why `xcopy "c:\source\" "d:\target\"` fails but `xcopy "c:\source" "d:\target\"`  works?

Both commands seems to have valid path references, and ... YES! both are valid path references, but there are two elements that work together to make the command fail:

- the folder reference is quoted (note: it *should* be quoted, it is a good habit to quote paths as you never know when they will contain spaces or special characters)
- `xcopy` is not an internal command handled by `cmd` but an executable file

As `xcopy` is an external command, its arguments are not handled following the `cmd` parser command line logic. They are handled by the [Microsoft C startup code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx).

This parser follows two sets of rules, official rules

> - Arguments are delimited by white space, which is either a space or a tab.
> - A string surrounded by double quotation marks is interpreted as a single argument, regardless of white space contained within. A quoted
>   string can be embedded in an argument. Note that the caret (`^`) is not
>   recognized as an escape character or delimiter.
> - A double quotation mark preceded by a backslash, `\"`, is interpreted as a literal double quotation mark (`"`).
> - Backslashes are interpreted literally, unless they immediately precede a double quotation mark.
> - If an even number of backslashes is followed by a double quotation mark, then one backslash (`\`) is placed in the argv array for every
>   pair of backslashes (`\\`), and the double quotation mark (`"`) is
>   interpreted as a string delimiter.
> - If an odd number of backslashes is followed by a double quotation mark, then one backslash (`\`) is placed in the argv array for every
>   pair of backslashes (`\\`) and the double quotation mark is interpreted
>   as an escape sequence by the remaining backslash, causing a literal
>   double quotation mark (`"`) to be placed in argv.

and undocumented/non official rules ([How Command Line Parameters Are Parsed](http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm))

> - Outside a double quoted block a `"` starts a double quoted block.
> - Inside a double quoted block a `"` followed by a different character (not another `"`) ends the double quoted block.
> - Inside a double quoted block a `"` followed immediately by another `"` (i.e. `""`) causes a single `"` to be added to the output, and the
>   double quoted block continues.

This parser sees the sequence `\"` found at the end of the *"first"* argument as a escaped quote that does not end/closes the argument, it is seen as part or the argument. And the *"starting"* quote of the *"second"* argument is just ending the double quoted block BUT not ending the argument, remember that arguments are delimited by white space.

So while it **seems** that the command line arguments are

```
     v           v            v......argument delimiters
      v.........v v..........v ......quoted blocks
xcopy "x:\souce\" "x:\target\"
       ^.......^   ^........^  ......argument data
       arg #1      arg #2

       arg #1 = x:\source\
       arg #2 = x:\target\
```

the actual argument handled by `xcopy` is

```
     v                        v .....argument delimiters
      v......................v  .....quoted block
xcopy "x:\souce\" "x:\target\"
       ^.....................^  .....argument data
      arg #1    

      arg #1 = x:\source" x:\target"
```

When the ending backslash is removed or the additional dot included, the closing quote in the argument will not be escaped, it will close the quoted block and the space between arguments will be seen as a delimiter.

Comment: `arg #1 = <x:\souce" >` (remove `<>`)
The double quoted block ends on the _first_ double quote of the target.

Comment: @MayraDelgado, no, the delimiter is the space. The first quote in the target just closes the quoted area, but after it there is not a space so the argument continues.

Comment: If you are using Macros like `$(TargetDir)` in your build events then unfortunately they contain a backslash on directories, so watch out for that.

Comment: That was the fix! Thank you! It was working fine locally on Visual Studio, but then would fail in Jenkins when using msbuild.

Comment: The suggestion to include the ending dot was the solution to my problem.