# error while using Forfiles command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to move a file from one server to another but getting error while using the below command

```
If Exist "D:\pkr\test.txt" %_ff%forfiles /p "D:\pkr\" /m "test.txt" /c "cmd /c echo @file && move /y @file "%cd%Appldata\pkr" " >> %_LOGG%
```

error msg: invalid argument/optional - '@file'

Comment: Remove the ending backslash in the path switch: `/p "D:\pkr"` or add a dot: `/p "D:\pkr\."`. More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25841519/2861476)

Comment: Why such a complicated command to just move a file.  I see no reason to use the `FORFILES` command at all.

Comment: With `forfiles`, you cannot use quotes within quotes; replace the inner quotes with `0x22`...