# Using a variable as a path BAT

Tags: batch-file, variables, path

I have a program that searchs for a file on the local disk, then copy it in its' own directory.

```
SET MyProgramDir=%~dp0
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('where /r c:\ *MyFile') do set MyPath=%%i
set MyFilePath=%MyPath:~0,-6%
xcopy "%MyFilePath%" "%MyProgramDir%"
```

But it says that the path is invalid; 0 file copied.
I don't get it, I tried with and without ", I tried to do like

```
set MyPath=%MyFilePath:~3%
set BatPath=%MyProgramDir:~3%
xcopy "C:\%MyPath" "C:\BatPath"
```

Comment: Other than `xcopy "C:\%MyPath" "C:\BatPath"` should be `xcopy "C:\%MyPath%" "C:\%BatPath%"` your routine works quite happily for me. What values are in `myprogramdir` and `myfilepath`?

Comment: Maybe it's because the directory contains characters like ÌÚÑ¶ÓÎÏ ..?

Comment: Here's the program anyway: http://pastebin.com/EFJCf6et

Comment: what does the directory contain?

Comment: More than likely the non-ASCII names. Try using the short names instead (dir /x ... will show the short name)

Comment: It is possible that you are not removing enough characters and you are ending in [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25840861/2861476)

Comment: Removing a backslash \ at the end fixed it. Thanks !