# ROBOCOPY changes input path names and does not work

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy

This is the code I have:

```
set thisfolder=%~dp0%
echo %thisfolder%

ROBOCOPY "%thisfolder%" "F:\batch testing\test\" copyself.bat
```

However the issue presents itself here:

```
F:\batch testing>set thisfolder=F:\batch testing\

F:\batch testing>echo F:\batch testing\
F:\batch testing\

F:\batch testing>ROBOCOPY "F:\batch testing\" "F:\batch testing\test\" copyself.bat

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Monday, March 5, 2018 7:26:54 AM
   Source : F:\batch testing" F:\batch\
     Dest : F:\batch testing\testing\test"\

    Files : copyself.bat

  Options : /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2018/03/05 07:26:54 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory F:\batch testing" F:\batch\
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

The source and destination paths seem distorted. Anyone know what's up with that?

Comment: [Different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25840861/2861476) but [same reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25841519/2861476). The ending backslash is escaping the closing quote.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was simple.

```
ROBOCOPY "F:\batch testing\"
```

should have been

```
ROBOCOPY "F:\batch testing"
```

Robocopy is extremely fickle...

Answer (score 1):

Given that your running script directory is also the current directory, I'd suggest changing `%~dp0%`, *(which should really have been `%~dp0`)*, to `%CD%`.

*Also, (as you've noticed), there should be no need to add a trailing backslash to your directory paths.*

In fact if you're only copying the running script itself, then I suppose it could just contain:

```bat
@RoboCopy "%CD%" "%CD%\test" "%~nx0"
```

Or if running it from another location:

Either:

```bat
@Start "" /D"%~dp0" "Cmd /C RoboCopy . .\test "%~nx0""
```

Or:

```bat
@Start "" /D"%~dp0" "%__AppDir__%RoboCopy.exe" . .\test "%~nx0"
```