# How to create a custom conda package from python files?

Tags: python, windows, conda, conda-build

I'm trying to write my first conda package consisting simply of python files. I'm following documentation from a few sources, including [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html) and [here](https://python-packaging-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conda.html).

#### My problem

When I run `conda-build` against my package directory, I get this error triggered from my `bld.bat`:

```DOS
(base) C:\Windows\system32>conda-build ./package-name --no-anaconda-upload
...
(%PREFIX%) %SRC_DIR%>xcopy ".\lib\" "%PREFIX%\Lib\site-packages\package-name\" /e
Invalid path
0 File(s) copied
```

From all of the `%...%` it would seem as though the environmental variables aren't being set properly.

**What am I doing wrong? Also, if there is a better/simpler way to build a package from a collection of scripts, I'm all ears.**

#### Further info

I have the following directory structure:

```
  package-name/
  ├── lib/
  │   ├── python-file1.py
  │   ├── python-file2.py
  │   └── ...
  ├── bld.bat
  ├── build.sh
  └── meta.yaml
```

My `meta.yaml` looks like:

```yaml
package:
  name: package-name
  version: 1.0

source:
  path: .

requirements:
  host:
    - python
  run:
    - python
    ...
```

any my `bld.bat` looks like this:

```DOS
xcopy ".\lib\" "%PREFIX%\Lib\site-packages\package-name\" /e
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

The idea being that all of source files are in the `./lib` directory and that they should be copied to `site-packages` of the installing environment.

n.b. I'm using conda 4.10.3 and conda-build 3.21.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that [`xcopy` doesn't like trailing slashes in the source parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25841519/745808). Also I should have put the `/e` switch before the arguments.

So my `bld.bat` should have looked like this:

```DOS
xcopy /e ".\lib" "%PREFIX%\Lib\site-packages\package-name\"
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```